# How to wrap Font-Awesome with CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using bootstrap & font awesome, and i am looking to make something like this:

I have this:
[image: what I have]

I want something like this:
[image: what I want]

Markup:

```
<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-paperclip icon-alert"></i> Everything was edited!</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon-alert {
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set a height to the container and then you can hide the overflow of the nested font-awesome icon, using `overflow:hidden`.

**CSS**:

```css
.clipped-alert{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:55px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="clipped-alert alert alert-success">
    <i class="fa fa-paperclip fa-5x icon-alert pull-right text-success"></i> 
    Everything was edited!
</div>
```

---

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nobiy/4/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

You would create a container around the icon that has the property of `over-flow: hidden;`
You can then position the element inside however you want.

[http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/W9WC2/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/W9WC2/)